# In single-spa-angular URL Redirection Infinite Loop

Tags: single-spa-angular

I am create micro frontend using single-spa-angular which has 3 angular app but on it URL Redirection Infinite Loop

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed in single-spa-angular version 4.6.0. Also you will need to add NavigationStart to options in the same way you pass NgZone and Router in your main.single-spa.ts.

You can see the github issue here: https://github.com/single-spa/single-spa-angular/issues/113 .